# How to add dynamic term/ordering to the following sort function?

Tags: javascript, sorting

This is a basic sorting function:

```
filteredItems () {
  return this.model
    .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.updatedAt) - new Date(a.updatedAt))
  }
}
```

I want to be able to dynamically set the sorting `term` and `order`:

```
sort: {
  term: 'updatedAt',
  order: '-1'
}
```

How to reflect that in the code above?

**EDIT:**

I realized the sorting function only works for dates. It doesn't, say, work with name and other fields. Is there a way to create a function that sorts everything?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically" ?

Comment: @Guig By feeding an object to the sort function (`sort` in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
filteredItems (sort) {
  return this.model
    .sort((a, b) => parseInt(sort.order) * (new Date(b[sort.term]) - new Date(a[sort.term])))
  }
}

var sort= {
  term: 'updatedAt',
  order: '-1'
}
```

Array.prototype.sort(fn) is designed to sort everything, if you want to make it more types use compare function as param, like `filteredItems((a, b) => parseInt(sort.order) * (new Date(b[sort.term]) - new Date(a[sort.term])))`